# How to route all express pages to a unique pages (Without html extension)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a bunch of pages in my static-content folder

```
index.html
about.html
dashboard.html
```

How do route all of these to their page without having .html in the url. I want to this in one method without having to do it like this:

```
app.route('/about').get(function(req, res) { 
        return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static-content/about.html')); 
});

app.route('/dashboard').get(function(req, res) { 
        return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static-content/dashboard.html')); 
});

www.mysite.com/about
www.mysite.com/dashboard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static) available options, you can make this work with using `extensions: ['html']` within the `express.static`.

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {
  extensions: ['html']
}));
```